# Add & remove classes with fewer lines of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to learn how to shorten my jQuery code. Any suggestions or tips would be awesome:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 

  $('#checkout_timeline #timeline-4').click(function() {
    if ($('#checkout_timeline #timeline-4').hasClass('active')) {
      $('#checkout-payment-container').addClass('cpc-visible');
    } 
  });

  $('#checkout_timeline #timeline-1, #checkout_timeline #timeline-2, #checkout_timeline #timeline-3').click(function() {
    $('#checkout-payment-container').removeClass('cpc-visible');
  });

});
```

To avoid clutter, please find the working version here:
[My JSFiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/b5srsk1z/)

I know I can use `.show()` and `.hide()` but due to other CSS considerations I want to apply `.cpc-visible`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a handful of things you can improve here. First, you're over-specifying. Ids are unique. No need to select `#checkout_timeline #timeline-4` when just `#timeline-4` will do. But why even have ids for each `li`? You can reference them by number using the `:nth-child(n)` selector. Or better yet, you've already given them application-specific class names like `billing`, `shipment`, and `payment`. Use those! Let's simplify the original content to:

```
<ul id="checkout_timeline">
  <li class='billing'>Billing</li>
  <li class='shipping'>Shipping</li>
  <li class='confirm'>Confirm</li>
  <li class='payment active'>Payment</li>
</ul>

<div id='checkout-payment-container' class='cpc-visible'>
  This is the container to show and hide.
</div>
```

Notice I left the `active` class, and indeed further initialized the checkout 
div with `cpc-visible` to mirror the payment-is-active condition. Usually I would keep HTML as simple as possible and put "starting positions" initialization in code. But "in for a penny, in for a pound." If we start with payment active, might as well see that decision through, and start the dependent div in a consistent state.

Now, revised JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
  $('#checkout_timeline li').click(function() {
    // make clicked pane active, and the others not
    $('#checkout_timeline li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    // show payment container only if payment pane active
    var paymentActive = $(this).hasClass('payment');
    $('#checkout-payment-container').toggleClass('cpc-visible', paymentActive);
  });
});
```

This code is much less item-specific. It doesn't try to add separate click handlers for different tabs/panes. They all get the same handler, which makes a uniform set of decisions. First, that whichever pane is clicked, make it active and the others not active. It does this by removing all `active` classes, then putting `active` on just the currently selected pane. Second, it asks "is the current pane the payment pane?" And it uses the `toggleClass` API to set the `cpc-visible` class accordingly. Often such "set class based on a boolean condition" logic is simpler and more reliable than trying to pair appropriate `addClass` and `removeClass` calls.

And we're done. Here's [a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jonathaneunice/7d98kz25/2/) that shows this in action.

Comment: Thank you so much for this clear explanation and one a notice line myself can follow, it gives me a better way to write my code with fewer lines of code, while not applying 4 separate click events.

Comment: Since you liked that, here is a [further refinement](https://jsfiddle.net/jonathaneunice/rdn5ummj/). It shoes a few more tricks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : You can user jquery selector with `timeline` and `active` class to bind click event handler where you can add required class. Same selector but not having `active` class to remove class.

This will be useful when you add / remove elements and will be more flexible.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
  $('#checkout_timeline .timeline.active').click(function() {
      $('#checkout-payment-container').addClass('cpc-visible');
  });
  $('#checkout_timeline .timeline:not(.active)').click(function() {
     $('#checkout-payment-container').removeClass('cpc-visible');
  });
});
```

**[JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5srsk1z/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the ways, you can shorten this code by using `:not()`. Also its better to use elements than to reference and get them via JQuery always.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var showHideContainer = $('#checkout-payment-container');
  $('#checkout_timeline .timeline.active').click(function() {
    showHideContainer.addClass('cpc-visible');
  });

  $('#checkout_timeline .timeline:not(.payment)').click(function() {
    showHideContainer.removeClass('cpc-visible');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code its working fine with fiddle

```
   $('.timeline').click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active') && $(this).attr("id") == "timeline-4")
          $('#checkout-payment-container').addClass('cpc-visible');
        else
         $('#checkout-payment-container').removeClass('cpc-visible');
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

This would of been my approach cause you still have to add/remove the active class between each li.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('ul li').click(function() {
    $('ul li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');

    k();
  });

  var k = (function() {
    return $('#timeline-4').hasClass('active') ? $('#checkout-payment-container').addClass('cpc-visible') : $('#checkout-payment-container').removeClass('cpc-visible');
  });

});
```

```css
#checkout-payment-container {
  float: left;
  display: none;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  height: 300px;
  width: 305px;
  padding: 5px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0px;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 11px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li.active {
  background: black;
}

.cpc-visible {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="checkout_timeline">
  <li id='timeline-1' class='timeline billing'>Billing</li>
  <li id='timeline-2' class='timeline shipping'>Shipping</li>
  <li id='timeline-3' class='timeline confirm'>Confirm</li>
  <li id='timeline-4' class='timeline payment'>Payment</li>
</ul>


<div id='checkout-payment-container'>
  This is the container to show and hide.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code look great, i would have written it the same.
bit sure how much it helps but if you like, you can use inline if like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#B').click(function() { (!$('#B').hasClass('active')) ? 
  $('#A').addClass('active') : ''; });          
  $('#C').click(function() { $('#A').removeClass('active'); });
});
```

Link for a live example:
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jpxh7w7f)